# How to export public key from .jks file using Keytool?

Tags: wso2, keytool

Right now I'm just trying to change my hostname in WSO2 by following this guide:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Changing+the+hostname

I've come to Step 4 after generating a .jks file called newkeystore.jks and in this step it should export the public key when I run this in command line:

```
keytool -export -alias certalias -keystore newkeystore.jks -file <public key name>.pem
```

I've tried this and I receive the error "The system cannot find the specified file."

My system environment variables are set so I can use keytool properly. I can see that the .jks file is generated and it is not empty. I'm not sure what the problem here is.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To me-in-the-past,

Don't waste your time following that guide. I find WSO2 documentation quite unhelpful, and I prefer to learn about WSO2 from outside sources than WSO2 itself. So what you need to do here is, while following the guide, for your command line:

```
keytool -export -alias newcert -keystore newkeystore.jks -file [insert any name here for your public key].pem
```

This should work!

Comment: Thank you for identifying this bug in the documentation and for providing your feedback. I am sorry to hear that you have had a bad experience using WSO2 docs. We are constantly working towards improving the documentation. This particular documentation has been fixed now [1] with the correct commands. [1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Changing+the+hostname

Comment: I am trying to export the public key. I am getting a binary file instead of a plaintext key.

Comment: more than likely you are getting a der encoded certificate.  you should read this:https://support.ssl.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/19/0/der-vs-crt-vs-cer-vs-pem-certificates-and-how-to-convert-them

Comment: aren't you getting the whole certificate with this command instead of 'just' the public key?

Comment: To export the certificate in PEM format  instead of DER add the -rfc option.  Ref:  http://www.herongyang.com/Cryptography/Certificate-Format-keytool-Export-in-DER-and-PEM.html

Comment: I found this thread trying to export the public key. This thread does not show how to export the pubic key it explains how to export the public certificate. Public key is not the same thing as the public certificate. A public certificate contains more than just the public key. I needed to find the public key from 2 certificates in order to see that they are created from the same key.

Answer (score 3):

Look here:
https://www.directutor.com/content/extracting-public-and-private-keys-java-key-store

> Step 3: Extract the “public key” from the “public-private”

```
keytool -export -alias client -keystore keystore.jks -rfc -file public.cert
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 $keytool -list -rfc -keystore ${store} -storepass ${password}
```

Comment: Please add some descriptions of how this command solves the problem.